# Is it possible to take a screenshot of an open browser window that includes the area hidden by a scroll bar?

Tags: macos

I am in need of a screenshot of an entire web page that has a height much greater than my physical screen. I am able to take multiple screenshots as I scroll down the page and then manually stitch them together on graphic design software, but ideally I could take a screen shot that does not require this extra step. Does anyone have any solutions, either first-party or through a third-party Mac application?

Comment: Don't you want to reduce the browser's window size and take the screenshot?

Comment: [Awesome screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/) (chrome) and [Awesome screenshot plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/screenshot-capture-annotate/) (firefox) both have an option to capture an entire web page. I guess a lot of other tools (either browser plugins or desktop apps) propose the same options.

Comment: @prabhakaran When you say reduce window size do you mean the zoom out feature? The pages I need are generally much longer than would fit in the viewport even if zoomed out to maximum (tested on Safari). Thank you for the suggestion though! And let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Zeitounator Awesome Screenshot works great! I don't know why a google search of this didn't show them. Thank you so much!